# Broken URL Encoding?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

Question 24672055 [is linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672055/app-closes-after-inputing-%C4%8D-%C5%A1-and-%C5%BE-characters-textview-displays-%EF%BF%BD) from the Stack Overflow front page, with the URL:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672055/app-closes-after-inputing-č-š-and-ž-characters-textview-displays-%EF%BF%BD`

However, following the link results in a 400 Bad Request - Invalid URL.

I tried working around this by using `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672055`, but that redirects to the full URL, and therefore has the same problem.

Comment: The question can be edited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24672055/edit), I'll leave it as is so your bug report still makes sense.

Comment: +1. I just encountered another example of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677241/is-fn-ogn-%D3%A8gn-or-omegagn (until it was edited).